# Preg Replace Pattern Confusion with Single Quotes

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

I have the below pattern which works fine but I'm trying to add in a case for single quote but no matter what I do I can't get the single quote to work with the pattern, I've tried escaping is etc. with no luck!?

```
$title = preg_replace_callback('/(\"|\()([a-z])/', function($m) {
     return strtoupper($m[0]);
}, $title);
```

I've tried the below but it doesn't seem to work.

```
'/(\"\'|\()([a-z])/'
```

Comment: Try: `/((\"|\')|\()([a-z])/` Does that do the trick for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put all the three chars inside a character class. This `\"\'` would look for double quote as-well as the following  single quote. If there isn't any , then it won't do the replacement.

```
$title = '"foo(bar)"';
echo preg_replace_callback('/[\'"(]([a-z])/', function($m) {
     return strtoupper($m[0]);
}, $title);
```

**Output:**

```
"Foo(Bar)"
```

Comment: or `'/[\'"(]\K([a-z])/'`

Comment: That did it, can I add in \s before it to make sure a space is before the character?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, space before any of the character cases?

Comment: provide an example along with expected output. you mean this `'/\s[\'"(]([a-z])/'` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, if you're devoted to SO 24/7, run for [moderator](http://stackoverflow.com/election) .........

Comment: @AvinashRaj, An example would be `Test 'Word'` or `Test "Word"` or `Test (Word)`, so that it doesn't affect words like `they're`.

Comment: try the regex in the above comment.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, perfect, fairplay to you!